# Form inside hidden div is still displaying in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

The form within the `div` is supposed to be hidden, but it isn't in FireFox. In Safari it is fine.

```
<div id="add_task" style="display:none;">
<form id="add_task_form">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Works for me, if you're using XHTML you might want to add a `/>` to the end of your input element, can you tell us what version of FF you are using?

Comment: @F0RR - django tag removed, since this has nothing to do with Django.

Comment: FF v3.5.7
I dont think it is html. Even if i have a <form> some text </form>, the form is still not hiding?

Answer (score 3):

Chances are your HTML is malformed somewhere else in the page (like not closing a tag) causing the structure of the page to be randomly determined by the browser. Try validating it with the w3c validator.

Comment: I dont think it is html. Even if i have a <form>  some text </form>, the form is still not hiding?

Comment: Who said anything about thinking? I said validate. There's a HUGE difference. Anything wrong with ANY part of the page can cause unexpected results if it affects the DOM. So validate.